# Finding corrupted files

Tags: osx, file-copy, corruption

I have a directory that have zillions of files. As soon as I try to copy this directory, I receive a message that a file could not be copied (corrupt ?) and the copy stops.

Is there any command I can type on terminal that can check all files on that directory tree and list all files that could not be copied or that are corrupt? I would not like to copy the files at this time, just to check if files would not be possible to copy/read if I try.

I am on OS X Mountain Lion but any unix command should work fine, I hope.

thanks.

NOTE: by corrupt I mean a file that cannot be read or copied.

Comment: Note that the best solution of course is to use a competent filesystem that's able to detect and fix corruption. A monthly run of `zpool scrub zroot` is a good way to ensure you never lose data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `rsync` can be used to copy directories, and is capable of restarting the copy from the point at which it terminated if any error causes the `rsync` to die.

   Using rsync's `--dry-run` option you can see what would be copied without actually copying anything.  The `--stats` and `--progress` options would also be useful.  and `--human-readable` or `-h` is easier to read.

   e.g.

   `rsync --dry-run -avh --stats --progress /path/to/src/ /path/to/destination/`

   I'm not sure if rsync is installed by default on Mac OS X, but I have used it on Macs so I know it's definitely available.
2. For a quick-and-dirty check on whether files in a subdirectory can be read or not, you could use `grep -r XXX /path/to/directory/ > /dev/null`.  The search regexp doesn't matter, because output is being discarded anyway.

   STDOUT is being redirected to /dev/null, so you'll only see errors.

   The only reason I chose `grep` here was because of its `-r` recursion option.  There are many other commands that could be used instead of `grep` here, and even more if used with `find`.

Comment: Just for information: On Linux, the `grep -r` solution also needs the `-a` option argument for this solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple function that uses `grep`.

If `grep` on macOS doesn't support `-a` and `-r` options, just install GNU `grep` with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```bash
brew install grep
```

My `findCorruptedFilesIn` function :

```bash
findCorruptedFilesIn () {
    local grep=$(which ggrep 2>/dev/null || which grep)
    time $grep -a -r . "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

And you can use it like this :

```bash
$ findCorruptedFilesIn Videos/
/bin/grep: Videos/CHRIST/Joel_Osteen/Daily_Wisdom_TV/Positioning_Yourself_to_Prosper_TD_Jakes__18__sICQGp3iIfc__youtube_com.mp4: Input/output error

real    17m25.045s
user    0m0.654s
sys     1m46.749s
```